# Hadoop Resource Manager ip address from namenode

Tags: rest, hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn, jmx

I am trying to find out the cluster info for hadoop management, using http://hadoop-namenode-address:50070/jmx. I managed to get the list of datanodes in the cluster but couldn't get info about secondary namenode, resourcemanager and nodemanager IP addresses.

Is there any way to find it out from the namenode, using REST API?

Comment: Use Hadoop's `FileSystem` API. There should be a method called `getConf`. You can get the configuration name from `hdfs-default.xml`

Comment: But how to get the info about secondary namenode from a namenode server @philantrovert

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get information about the secondary namenode, resource manager and node managers from the namenode. The namenode only knows about datanodes.  While all of these servers are part of Hadoop, the resource manager and node managers are the compute part while the namenode, secondary namenode and datanodes are the data part and both can be run independently of each other.

If you're using either Cloudera Manager, or Ambari you can use their respective APIs to identify the services you need or (as @philantrovert suggested)
scrape the configs from the Hadoop xmls (hdfs-site.xml and yarn-site.xml).